# how do i tell google that my landing page is a blog?

Tags: seo, google, sitemap

I have written my own very simple CMS and everything i publish on my page will go on the landing page (http://xyious.com). so every time i write a new page, regardless of where it ends up on the navigation, it will also go on the homepage, very much like a blog. Now i have already submitted a sitemap that tells google that the landing page changes very frequently (daily), although it doesn't change that often.

Is there any way to tell google that the landing page is essentially a blog ?

Is there a way to tell google that there is duplicate content because obviously the landing page has the same content as a page in the archives ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no specific requirement to tell Google this, millions of websites are blog sites and they manage just fine.

Each blog post should have it's own linked-to dedicated URL however (permalink - normally the article title is linked), and the XML sitemap should refer to this URL.

Looking at your site, however, there are additional duplicate content issues where your content is appearing under multiple URLs (home page, /Miscellaneous, /Miscellaneous/Starcraft.php etc), and your "home page" at / is different from your linked-to home page at /Home/index.php, as well as having no-www and www versions of every page.

I'd suggest you take a look at other popular Blog/CMS systems (Wordpress/Drupal etc) to see how they handle home-page vs posts/pages.